# How to solve some Pauli matrix mixed differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra

This equation is about quantum.

$$H_0(-i\partial_x,k_y)=(m-t_x\partial^2_x/2)\sigma_z\tau_z-iA\partial_x\sigma_xs_z$$
When solving the eigenvalue equation $H_0\psi_a(x)=E_a\psi_a(x)$,the boundary condition is $\psi_a(0)=\psi(-\infty)=0$,I want to calculate eigenstate for $E_a=0$.

I have konwn the solution is $$\psi_a(x)=N_xsin(k_1x)e^{k_2x}e^{ik_yy}\chi_a$$
with the normalization constant $N_x=2\sqrt{k_2(k_1^2+k2^2)/k_1^2}$and two parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$ given by 
$$k_1=\sqrt{-\frac{2m}{t_x}-\frac{A_x^2}{t_x^2}}\qquad    k_2=\frac{A_x}{t_x}$$
$\chi_a$are eigenvectors satisfying $\sigma_ys_z\tau_z\chi_a=\chi_a$

Above both $\sigma_i,s_i, and \tau_i$are [Pauli matrix](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pauli_matrices)

I want to solve this equation,but don't known how to do get this solution,anyone could help me,thanks.